# how to preview video camera from tv tuner in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how can i preview / record or only preview video from my tv tuner card in vb.net....i have usb stick deny tuner card in my laptop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of TV capture cards, webcams etc support DirectShow. A few months ago I was looking at how easy it would be to capture video from C# and it can be done. [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) is a wrapper around most of the DirectShow APIs. There are also a couple of commercial DirectShow controls for .NET like [VisionLAB](http://www.mitov.com/html/directshow_video_capture_in__n.html). I've not used them myself and it looks pretty complicated, but it can be done.

Otherwise, as Red-nosed unicorn suggests you might need to start reading the vendor's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on your TV card. Does the vendor provide an API documentation? This would specify how the TV card can be addressed programmatically.

Comment: could you please let me in detail about the whole process of api or any process